# Need pytorch help doing 2D convolutions of N images with N kernels all at once

Tags: pytorch

I have a torch tensor which is a stack of images. Let's say for kicks it is

```
im=th.arange(4*5*6,dtype=th.float32).view(4,5,6)
```

which is a `4x5x6` tensor, meaning four `5x6` images stacked vertically.

I want to convolve each layer with its own 2-D kernel so that

```
I_{out,j} = k_j*I_{in,j}, j=(1...4)
```

I can obviously do this with a for loop, but I'd like to take advantage of GPU acceleration and do all the convolutions at the same time. No matter what I try, I've only been able to use torch's `conv2d` or `conv3d` to produce a single output layer that is the sum of all the 2d convolutions. Or I can make 4 layers where each is the same sum of all the 2d convolutions. Here's a concrete example. Let's use `im` as defined above. Say that the kernel is defined by

```
k=th.zeros((4,3,3),dtype=th.float32)
n=-1
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        n+=1
        k[n,i,j]=1
        k[n,2,2]=1
print(k)

tensor([[[1., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1.]],

        [[0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1.]],

        [[0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1.]],

        [[0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1.]]])
```

and from above, `im` is

```
tensor([[[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.],
         [  6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.],
         [ 12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.],
         [ 18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,  22.,  23.],
         [ 24.,  25.,  26.,  27.,  28.,  29.]],

        [[ 30.,  31.,  32.,  33.,  34.,  35.],
         [ 36.,  37.,  38.,  39.,  40.,  41.],
         [ 42.,  43.,  44.,  45.,  46.,  47.],
         [ 48.,  49.,  50.,  51.,  52.,  53.],
         [ 54.,  55.,  56.,  57.,  58.,  59.]],

        [[ 60.,  61.,  62.,  63.,  64.,  65.],
         [ 66.,  67.,  68.,  69.,  70.,  71.],
         [ 72.,  73.,  74.,  75.,  76.,  77.],
         [ 78.,  79.,  80.,  81.,  82.,  83.],
         [ 84.,  85.,  86.,  87.,  88.,  89.]],

        [[ 90.,  91.,  92.,  93.,  94.,  95.],
         [ 96.,  97.,  98.,  99., 100., 101.],
         [102., 103., 104., 105., 106., 107.],
         [108., 109., 110., 111., 112., 113.],
         [114., 115., 116., 117., 118., 119.]]])
```

The right answer is easy if I do the for loop:

```
import torch.functional as F
for i in range(4):
    print(F.conv2d(im[i].expand(1,1,5,6),k[i].expand(1,1,3,3)))

tensor([[[[14., 16., 18., 20.],
          [26., 28., 30., 32.],
          [38., 40., 42., 44.]]]])
tensor([[[[ 75.,  77.,  79.,  81.],
          [ 87.,  89.,  91.,  93.],
          [ 99., 101., 103., 105.]]]])
tensor([[[[140., 142., 144., 146.],
          [152., 154., 156., 158.],
          [164., 166., 168., 170.]]]])
tensor([[[[201., 203., 205., 207.],
          [213., 215., 217., 219.],
          [225., 227., 229., 231.]]]])
```

As I noted earlier, the only thing I've been able to get is one sum of those four output images (or four copies of the same summed layer):

```
F.conv2d(im.expand(1,4,5,6),k.expand(1,4,3,3)) 

tensor([[[[430., 438., 446., 454.],
          [478., 486., 494., 502.],
          [526., 534., 542., 550.]]]])
```

I'm certain that what I want to do is possible, I just haven't been able to wrap my head around it yet. Does anyone have a solution to offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward if you use a grouped convolution.

From [the `nn.Conv2d` documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Conv2d)

> At `groups=in_channels`, each input channel is convolved with its own
>   set of filters

Which is exactly what we want.

The shape of the `weights` argument to `F.conv2d` needs to be considered since it changes depending on the value of `groups`. The first dimension of `weights` should just be `out_channels`, which is 4 in this case. The second dimension according to [F.conv2d docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.conv2d) should be `in_channels / groups`, which is 1. So we can perform the operation using

```
F.conv2d(im.unsqueeze(0), k.unsqueeze(1), groups=4).squeeze(0)
```

which produces a tensor of shape `[4,3,4]` with values

```
tensor([[[ 14.,  16.,  18.,  20.],
         [ 26.,  28.,  30.,  32.],
         [ 38.,  40.,  42.,  44.]],

        [[ 75.,  77.,  79.,  81.],
         [ 87.,  89.,  91.,  93.],
         [ 99., 101., 103., 105.]],

        [[140., 142., 144., 146.],
         [152., 154., 156., 158.],
         [164., 166., 168., 170.]],

        [[201., 203., 205., 207.],
         [213., 215., 217., 219.],
         [225., 227., 229., 231.]]])
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much. That also makes grouping totally clear!